# XRDP keeps giving me file is read-only

Tags: eclipse, xrdp

I'm using Eclipse with the RED plugin on Ubuntu with XRDP and it keeps giving me this message when I try to edit and save any file.

[image]

The folder has all the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Never used Eclipse so not sure what the problem could be but I would guess that since you are using xRDP software solution, it might be related to the polkit authorization framework.  When connected remotely, you do not have all the privileges you would normally have when connected locally on the system...

You can try to follow the instructions provided in this post in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487226/xrdp-windows-remote-desktop-restricts-all-groups-except-root/1490769#1490769) and see if this could fix your issue.

**Use this at your own risk**

In a nutshell, follow these instructions

```
#create a pkla file 
sudo touch /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/48-udisks.pkla

#open/edit the file as sudo
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/48-udisks.pkla

#Copy the code below into the file and save it  

[udisks]
Identity=unix-group:*
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

The file tells that any users logged remotely can perform any actions in order to manage disks.

Again, not sure this would work and not sure about the syntax...

Hope this help
Till next time